# I cannot pull values from an array in a different class

Tags: java, arrays, swing

The printout of the array lifegrid2 just gives all zeros.  I tested the lifegrid array in MyPanel and that is populating, but the values are pulling through as zeros.  I checked by putting some values in lifegrid2 and they are being wiped, so it is pulling through from MyPanel, but only zeros.  There are no errors being reported.

I have made a small test program with a 2d array which does pull values through.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;

  import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 

public class SwingPaintDemo3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,800));
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton start = new JButton("START");
    subPanel.add(start);
    start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae1) {
            System.out.println("START");
            int [][][] lifegrid2 = new int [12][12][2];
            int temp;
            
            for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<12; j++) {
            **MyPanel obj = new MyPanel();
            temp = obj.lifegrid [i][j][0];
                lifegrid2 [i][j][0] = temp;**
                if (j<11) 
                    {System.out.print(lifegrid2 [j] [i] [0]);}
                else 
                    {System.out.println(lifegrid2 [j] [i] [0]);}}}
            
            
            
                                        }   
    });
    f.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    
} 

}




import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
```

import javax.swing.JPanel;

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

public int [][][] lifegrid = new int [12][12][2];

private int squareX = 1280;
private int squareY = 800;
private int gridX, gridY ;

public MyPanel() {

           
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            squareX = e.getX();
            squareY = e.getY();
                            if ((squareX>50 & squareX <550) & (squareY>50 & squareY <550) ){
                gridX =(squareX-50)/50+1;
                gridY =(squareY-50)/50+1;
                
                squareX = (squareX -50)/50 * 50 + 50;
                squareY = (squareY -50)/50 * 50 + 50;
                System.out.println(gridX + " " + gridY);
                lifegrid [gridX] [gridY] [0] = 1;
                
                repaint(squareX,squareY,50,50);}
            else {
                            }
        }
        });
     
                             }







protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       
    g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(squareX,squareY,48,48);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(squareX,squareY,48,48);
}  
}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mre] demonstrating your problem. An MRE should be posted with every question. The MRE forces you to simplify the problem.

Comment: *so it is pulling through from MyPanel, but only zeros.* - why would you expect them to be anything but zeros? When you create a new instance of the class it will be 0. The user hasn't had an opportunity to click on anything yet. Your whole design need to be rethought. I gave some suggestions below.

Answer (score 1):

> I have made a small test program with a 2d array

```
int [][][] lifegrid2 = new int [12][12][2];
```

That is a 3D array.

A 2D array is defined as:

```
int [][] lifegrid2 = new int [12][12];
```

The logic to initialize the array belongs in the constructor of your class:

```
MyPanel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            lifegrid [i][j] = 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then your paintComponent() method needs to iterate through the 2D grid and only paint the grids that have a value of 1.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
 
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            if (lifegrid[i][j] = 1)
               // paint the grid
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Edit:

As best as I can tell you are trying to create a grid based game. When you click on a cell in the grid the cell turns red. The are two common ways to approach this:

1. `Use components.` In this approach you have a parent panel using a `GridLayout` and you add a child panel to each cell in the grid. You would also add your MouseListener to each child panel. When you click on the child panel you change the background of the panel to red.
2. `Do custom painting`. In this approach you have a single JPanel. This class keep a 2D Array for the "state" of each cell in the grid. You add a single MouseListener to the panel. When you click on the panel you determine which cell was clicked and then you update the state of that cell. In the paintComponent() method you iterate through the 2D Array and paint each cell where that state has changed.

Your approach seems to be some kind of hybrid between the two and is not working.

Comment: It IS meant to be a 3d array.  The paint part is doing what I want it to do.  The problem is that lifegrid2 in my main method is being populated with zero values.  I extended my test code to 3d and it works fine.   I also tried initializing the array with no luck

Comment: *It IS meant to be a 3d array.* - 1) that is not what your question states. 2) none of your code indicates any reason for a 3D array. You only ever access the 3rd index with a value of 0. *The paint part is doing what I want it to do.* - you are still not understanding the concept of custom painting. You should NOT be creating 144 panels and have each panel paint an individual square. You SHOULD have a single panel paint each of the 144 squares based on the value in the 2D array.

Comment: *The problem is that lifegrid2 in my main method is being populated with zero values.*  that is the default when you create an int array, what do you expect the values to be? Where do you change the value? You have two different arrays defined in 2 different classes. If you update the value in one class why do you think it would update the array in another class?

Comment: It is a work in progress, the other part of the array will be used.  I have already written the code for that and it is fine.  The test program is now also 3d.  i know that lifegrid2 starts with zero values.  The problem is that those zeros should have some 1s in where I have clicked the mouse.  They are not pulling through from MyPanel in the highlighted code.

Comment: *They are not pulling through from MyPanel in the highlighted code.* - why do you think they should "pull through"??? They are two separate variables in two separate classes. I have already suggested the better way to design the class.